# gcroot has no value

Tags: exception, visual-c++, c++-cli, handle, mixed-mode

I have a curious problem with a managed object in unmanaged code. I have this C++/CLI module that bridges C++ and C# code. I have a structure like this:

```
template <class T>
struct ManagedReference
{
  gcroot<T^> addonHost;
}
```

Now, at some point I create an instance of this managed reference and set the addonHost. All is well, I am able to use the handle.

[image]

However, in some cases (would require to much contextual description I'm afraid) the value cannot be evaluated:

[image]

In this case, calling a method with addonHost results in a "Entry point for found" exception.

As you can see from the screenshots, it is not two difference instances, two different handles. It's the very same. I don't understand how come in some situation the "value" is not evaluated. And maybe how I could catch that. Because it's not null.

What I should also mention is that I have several `gcroot<T>` and all of them have this problem, except one that is a `gcroot<System::String>`.

UPDATE

Here is what debugger shows during execution. The object is created and available, then at some point, the value is 'vanishing', and at the next call it's still there. But this is very reproducible. It's not random.

```
handle  0x0E1618EC  void*
 value  0x106396d8 { m_host=0x10638e04 }    <-- object is available here

handle  0x0E1618EC  void*
 value  0x1020e558 { m_host=0x1020e4f0 }    <-- object moved in memory

handle  0x0E1618EC  void*
 value                                      <-- no value here

handle  0x0E1618EC  void*
 value  0x1020e558 { m_host=0x1020e4f0 }    <-- object 'is back'
```

Comment: What kind of gcroot<> class is this?  The Microsoft one has a _handle, not a handle and no value.

Comment: There might be certain object types that the debugger just can't read the value (dlls that were compiled an optimized, native objects that aren't known properly to the debugger), have you checked this ?

Comment: @hans, it's Microsoft's `gcroot`. and yes, it has a _handle, but the debugger shows a `handle` and a `value` as you can see from the screenshots. of course you could try it for yourself

Comment: @yochai, if it was solely for the debugger not showing `value`, I would not have started this thread; the problem is the condition `pInstance && pInstace->addonHost` evaluates to `true`, so then a call like `pInstace->addonHost->CallMethod()` happens and then I get a "Entry point for found" exception.

Comment: Well, I did.  You ought to check your autoexp.dat

Comment: gcroot<*>{
 children(
  #(
   handle: $c._handle,
   value: __gchandle($c._handle)
  )
  )
}

Comment: well, the display is different in native and managed context. in native it just displays _handle; in managed (C++/CLI code) it displays handle and value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help to initialize the `gcroot`.  Try:

```
template <class T>
struct ManagedReference
{
  gcroot<T^> addonHost;
  ManagedReference() : addonHost(nullptr) {}
};
```

Comment: just for the sake of being opened to ideas, I've tried it, but of course with no help. the `addonHost` is initialized immediately after an instance is created, and I am able to use it's value in most of the cases.

Comment: @Marius: So you're expecting that `pInstance->addonHost` should always be set correctly (should always evaluate as true in the `if` statement)?

Comment: yes, because, you see, after initialization, this piece of code is called several times, and in some cases, the value is not "found" (I don't know how to put it); but after that the next call, it works again

Comment: @Marius: Is it just the debugger that misbehaves (can't see the value), or does the program also get bad results sometimes?  There are some known debugger issues with `gcroot` variables and watch expressions.

Comment: yes, it's not just the debugger; it doesn't matter whether I run with the debugger or not, it doesn't matter whether it's Debug or Release config.